# Formalization of Kleene star idempotence in regular expressions

Tags: regex, agda

I'm trying to formalize some properties of regular expressions (RE's) in Agda. I've got stuck on the proof of idempotence of the Kleene star operation.

I've managed to prove that

```
xs <-[[ (e *) * ]] -> xs <-[[ e * ]]
```

i.e. if a string `xs` is in the language of RE `(e *) *` then it should be in `e *`. My problem is how can I prove the other side? (the hole in `lemmaKleeneIdem`)

```
xs <-[[ e * ]] -> xs <-[[ (e *) * ]]
```

Here's part of my formalisation:

```
open import Data.List as List
open import Data.List.Properties
open List-solver renaming (nil to :[] ; _⊕_ to _:++_; _⊜_ to _:==_)
open import Data.Product renaming (_×_ to _*_)

open import Relation.Binary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality renaming (_≡_ to _==_)
open import Relation.Nullary renaming (¬_ to not)

module Test {Token : Set}(eqTokenDec : Decidable {A = Token} _==_)  where

  infixr 5 _+_
  infixr 6 _o_
  infixl 7 _*

  data RegExp : Set where
    Emp : RegExp
    Eps : RegExp
    #_  : (a : Token) -> RegExp
    _o_ : (e e' : RegExp) -> RegExp
    _+_ : (e e' : RegExp) -> RegExp
    _*  : (e : RegExp) -> RegExp

  -- regular expression membership

  infix 3 _<-[[_]]
  infixr 6 _*_<=_
  infixr 6 _<+_ _+>_

  data _<-[[_]] : List Token -> RegExp -> Set where
    Eps    : List.[] <-[[ Eps ]]                       -- epsilon: empty string
    #_     : (a : Token) -> List.[ a ] <-[[ # a ]]     -- single token
    _*_<=_ : {xs ys zs : List Token}{e e' : RegExp}    -- concatenation of two REs
         (pr : xs <-[[ e ]])(pr' : ys <-[[ e' ]])
         (eq : zs == xs ++ ys) -> zs <-[[ e o e' ]]
    _<+_   : {xs : List Token}{e : RegExp}(e' : RegExp)  -- choice left
         -> (pr : xs <-[[ e ]]) -> xs <-[[ e + e' ]]           
    _+>_   : {xs : List Token}{e' : RegExp}(e : RegExp)   -- choice right
         -> (pr : xs <-[[ e' ]]) -> xs <-[[ e + e' ]]
    _*     : {xs : List Token}{e : RegExp} ->             -- Kleene star
         xs <-[[ Eps + e o e * ]]      ->
         xs <-[[ e * ]]


  -- regular expression equivalence

  infix 4 _:=:_

  _:=:_ : forall (e e' : RegExp) -> Set
  e :=: e' = forall (xs : List Token) -> (((pr : xs <-[[ e ]]) -> (xs <-[[ e' ]])) *
                                      ((pr : xs <-[[ e' ]]) -> (xs <-[[ e ]])))

  subsetLemma : forall {xs} e -> xs <-[[ e ]] -> xs <-[[ e * ]]
  subsetLemma {xs = xs} e pr = (_ +> pr * ((_ <+ Eps) *) <= solve 1 (\ xs -> xs :== xs :++ :[]) refl xs) *

  lemmaKleeneIdem : (e : RegExp) -> e * :=: (e *) *
  lemmaKleeneIdem e xs = subsetLemma (e *) , ?
```

Any tip on how should I proceed to complete this proof would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Include your code in the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because formal regular expressions are not the same as regular expressions in programming. This probably belongs on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ShafKhan Do not use code markup for things that are not code. And do not change US English to UK English, it's the author's choice.

Comment: @Barmar: It's a question of proving it in *Agda* which is a programming language.

Comment: OK, I've retracted. But you should post your code here, not as a link.

Comment: I have no idea what I just [wrote](http://lpaste.net/147462), but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sharing the solution:

```
  lemmaKleeneIdem : (e : RegExp) -> e * :=: (e *) *
  lemmaKleeneIdem e xs = subsetLemma (e *) , subsetLemma' e
                     where
                       mem : forall {xs e} -> xs <-[[ e ]] -> List _
                       mem {xs = xs} _ = xs

                       assoc1 : forall {A : Set}(xs ys zs : List A) -> (xs ++ ys) ++ zs == xs ++ (ys ++ zs)
                       assoc1 = solve 3 (\ xs ys zs -> (xs :++ ys) :++ zs :== xs :++ (ys :++ zs)) refl

                       lem' : forall {xs ys zs} e -> zs == xs ++ ys -> xs <-[[ e ]]  -> ys <-[[ e * ]] -> zs <-[[ e * ]]
                       lem' e refl pr pr' = (_ +> pr * pr' <= refl) *

                       lem : forall {xs ys zs} e -> zs == xs ++ ys -> xs <-[[ e * ]] -> ys <-[[ e * ]] -> zs <-[[ e * ]]
                       lem e refl ((.(e o e *) <+ Eps) *)    q = q
                       lem e eq ((.Eps +> p * p₁ <= refl) *) q rewrite assoc1 (mem p) (mem p₁) (mem q)
                           = lem' e eq p (lem e refl p₁ q)

                       subsetLemma' : forall {xs} e -> xs <-[[ e * * ]] -> xs <-[[ e * ]]
                       subsetLemma' e ((.(e * o e * *) <+ pr) *)   = ((e o e *) <+ pr) *
                       subsetLemma' e ((.Eps +> pr * pr₁ <= eq) *) = lem e eq pr (subsetLemma' e pr₁)

                       subsetLemma : forall {xs} e -> xs <-[[ e ]] -> xs <-[[ e * ]]
                       subsetLemma {xs = xs} e pr = (_ +> pr * ((_ <+ Eps) *) <= solve 1 (\ xs -> xs :== xs :++ :[]) refl xs) *
```

Comment: It would be better if you not only share a solution, but also describe what's going on in it.